# UDP broadcast Is there something wrong here?

Tags: networking, arduino, udp, broadcast, esp8266

I have a UDP Server listening on my local network on IP:192.168.0.53 port 1337.

I have a UDP client also on the same subnet of my local network setup to send a packet to 255.255.255.255 port 1337 **and it never arrives on my server**. This happens repeatedly, and I am using the broadcast address as you can see.

I try from my client to send a packet to 192.168.0.53 port 1337 **and it arrives fine**. Showing a simpler non broadcast route works nicely.

I have tried 2 clients, as I believe some special flags need to be set for broadcast. Both [PacketSender](https://packetsender.com) and this [specific broadcast application](https://github.com/stanwu/udp-broadcast) are not received by my client.

My server is written using the [ESP8266WiFi UDP class](http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-examples.html).

Am I missing something here? The broadcast should be received by my server but isn't. Do I need a special flag on my server perhaps?

The server code (based off of the Udp class linked above) simply is:

```
     int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize){
     // receive incoming UDP packets
    String msg = "Received ";
    msg += String(packetSize)+" bytes from IP:";
    msg += Udp.remoteIP().toString()+" on port:"+Udp.remotePort();
    this->DCPrintf(msg);

    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      incomingPacket[len] = 0;
    }
    msg = "UDP packet contents:";
    msg +=incomingPacket;
    this->DCPrintf(msg);

  }
```

Sending code from this github https://github.com/stanwu/udp-broadcast:

```
/* fpont 12/99 */
/* pont.net    */
/* udpClient.c */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset() */
#include <sys/time.h> /* select() */ 

//for Mac OS X
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REMOTE_SERVER_PORT 1500
#define MAX_MSG 100


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int sd, rc, i;
  struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, remoteServAddr;
  struct hostent *h;
  int broadcast = 1;

  /* check command line args */
  if(argc<3) {
    printf("usage : %s <server> <data1> ... <dataN> \n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* get server IP address (no check if input is IP address or DNS name */
  h = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if(h==NULL) {
    printf("%s: unknown host '%s' \n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("%s: sending data to '%s' (IP : %s) \n", argv[0], h->h_name,
     inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)h->h_addr_list[0]));

  remoteServAddr.sin_family = h->h_addrtype;
  memcpy((char *) &remoteServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, 
     h->h_addr_list[0], h->h_length);
  remoteServAddr.sin_port = htons(REMOTE_SERVER_PORT);

  /* socket creation */
  sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if(sd<0) {
    printf("%s: cannot open socket \n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }


  if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast,sizeof broadcast) == -1) {
          perror("setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)");
          exit(1);
  }

  /* bind any port */
  cliAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  cliAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  cliAddr.sin_port = htons(0);

  rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, sizeof(cliAddr));
  if(rc<0) {
    printf("%s: cannot bind port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }


  /* send data */
  for(i=2;i<argc;i++) {
    rc = sendto(sd, argv[i], strlen(argv[i])+1, 0, 
        (struct sockaddr *) &remoteServAddr, 
        sizeof(remoteServAddr));

    if(rc<0) {
      printf("%s: cannot send data %d \n",argv[0],i-1);
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
    }

  }

  return 1;

}
```

And the other client is simply the PacketSender software.

Comment: Send it to the subnet broadcast address `192.168.0.255`. Broadcasting to `255.255.255.255` has been deprecated for over twenty years.

Comment: @EJP weird did some reading and it suggested 255.255.255.255 should work. Nevertheless 192.168.0.255 didn't arrive on my server from either client. Again, unicast direct works fine.

Comment: You need to set SO_BROADCAST at the sender. Please post your sending code *here.*

Comment: added the code @EJP

Comment: @EJP can you clarify why my server doesn't receive my broadcast packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use multicast instead.

My server code was changed to join a multicast group and listen on a particular port:

```
int port=12345;
  IPAddress local=WiFi.localIP();

  IPAddress multicastGroup(233, 100, 100, 53);
  Udp.beginMulticast(local,multicastGroup,port);
```

Then I from any client sent a UDP packet to IP `233.100.100.53` `port 12345`, which is the multicast group, and voila -- it works a treat!

Comment: Better choice anyway. It's more efficient at nodes that aren't listening for these packets.